# Clustering matrices with "2d interpretation"

Tags: clustering, k-means, matrix, image-processing

I am not sure if I can formulate this such that it is clear. :)

I have around 700 80x80 matrices, where each matrix shows some weather event (a matrix has continuous entries from 0 to 60). Now I would like to cluster these
events into several event types.

I already used a very simple method where I transformed each matrix into a vector, and did kmeans on these vectors with euclidean distance.

But is there no better method, that uses somehow more information (e.g. neighboring pixels)? It seems to me, that I loose alot of information if I cluster in such a fashion.

So maybe it is a general question:

*How to **cluster matrices**, where each entry has a "meaning" in 2 dimensions.*

Answer (score 1):

1. specify a distance or similarity measure that takes neighbor pixels into account. For example, a **quadratic form** may be helpful.
2. compute a distance matrix, 700x700
3. run hierarchical clustering

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Do you know of good distance/ similarity measures for example radar images?